# Integrate $f(x,y) = e^{-x^2-y^2}$ in a circle with radius $1$ and center at $(0,0)$

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

I am asked to integrate $f(x,y) = e^{-x^2-y^2}$ in a circle with radius $1$ and center at $(0,0)$.

The setup of the integral (in my solution) is

$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} e^{-r^2} r dr d\theta$$

which gives me

$$- \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{-1} e^u du d\theta = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \left( 1-1/e \right) d\theta = \frac{2\pi}{2} \left( 1-1/e \right) = \frac{\pi(e-1)}{e}$$

as a solution.

The answer from the book is

$$\pi(e-1)$$

Where did I go wrong? Or is the textbook wrong?

Comment: @AlexS sorry that was a typo, already fixed it.

Comment: in the inside integral the upper bonud is 1.

Comment: @kmitov not really. When you substitute u = -r^2 when r=1 then u=-1

Comment: ???  The answer you got and the answer you say was in the book are exactly the same!  Did you correcting the typo answer your question?

Comment: @kmitov:  your edit completely changed the question, in particular making the OPs answer agree with the book.  Please roll back

Comment: @user247327, someone edited and muddled the question.

Comment: i did the corrections back. Sorry.

Comment: @kmitov thank you for rolling back the edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u = -r^2$, then $du = -2r \, dr$.  And the limits change from $r=0$ and $r=1$ to $u = 0$ and $u=-1.$  So you get:

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{-1} -\frac{1}{2} e^u \, du \, d\theta, $$
which you correctly evaluated.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are to integrate over the disk, not the circle (which is just the perimeter), you are doing fine.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+exp(-x%5E2)x+from+0+to+1) agrees with you that $$\int_0^1 e^{-r^2}r\ dr=\frac{e-1}{2e}$$

Answer (score 0):

You have to compute
$$
\int_{0}^{1}re^{-r^2}\,dr
$$
which can't be negative. The substitution $-r^2=u$ gives
$$
-2r\,dr=du
$$
so the integral becomes
$$
-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{-1}e^u\,du=-\frac{1}{2}\Bigl[e^u\Bigr]_0^{-1}=
-\frac{1}{2}(e^{-1}-1)=\frac{1-e^{-1}}{2}
$$
Thus your original integral is
$$
2\pi\frac{1-e^{-1}}{2}=\pi(1-e^{-1})
$$